# How to stop "git push all" using git hook?

Tags: python, git, githooks

As the title says, how do I stop this "git push all" command. My config file is altered to contain two urls (as shown below) and therefore will git push to two servers upon "git push all".

**Part of config file:**

```
[remote "all"]
    url = C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\Machine1\\Server1
    url = C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\Machine2\\Server2
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/all/*
```

I've created a pre-push git hook that will basically create a lock.txt file in each of the servers, if it detects the presence of a similar lock file, everything retracts. Upon retract, I'll return an exit code of "1" to stop it from git pushing. A small part of the code is shown below.

**Part of git hook pre-push file:**

```
LockFileExist = False
for serverpath in cleanurls:
    for file in os.listdir(str(serverpath)):
        if "lock.txt" in file:
            LockFileExist = True
    if LockFileExist == False:
        Create_Lock(serverpath)
    else:
        print ("Stopped pushing, starting revert process..")
        exitcode = Revert_Process(createdlockfiles)
        if exitcode == 0:
            print ("Revert process has failed. Nothing to revert.")
        else:
            print ("Revert process is successful")
        print("Stopping the whole git process..")
        exit(1)
```

So, this is what is shown (below), pre-push file ran twice because git push all is treated as two separate commands when pushing to two separate servers. **However, what I wish for is for the command to end, the moment the first exit code is sent out.**

[image: Results]

Is this even possible? I'm open to any suggestions. One more way I can think of is to stop the whole command line window but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it. If you need any more codes for testing, do let me know! Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like a server deployment?  A deployment tool, such as Capistrano, would make this a lot easier and more robust.

Answer (score 0):

I've not figure out the total solution, but I'm making use of the script to go around this problem. The idea is by using a text file to note down the current state of the git process. With that information, I can use if statements that acts like switches for me to toggle between them. The code is long, so here is a rough idea.

I'm using three states:

```
1) Enabled - To allow git hook to run
2) Disabled - To stop all the other git push
3) Neutralized - To stop git hook but allow other git push to run
```

Rough code structure:

```
#reads from file
LockSystemToggle = 0
if "Disabled" in lockvariable:
    LockSystemToggle = 1
    f.close()
elif "Neutralized" in lockvariable:
    LockSystemToggle = 2
    f.close()
else:                                               
    f = open(lockdirectorypath, "w+")       #nothing much, just in case of empty file
    f.write("Locking System = Enabled")
    f.close()
if LockSystemToggle == 0:
    #runs initial git hook functions
    #file is "Neutralized" or "Disabled" here depending on situation
elif LockSystemToggle == 1:
    exit(1)   #skips initial git hook functions but blocks all git push
else:
    exit(0)   #skips initial git hook functions but continue git push
```

Not to worry about changing the file structure to "Enabled" for the next "git push all" because I'll be sending the command from another application, I could alter them there before pushing.